# How to cut video frame specific with ffmpeg and convert framerate?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, video-editing, framerate

since a couple of days i encounter a problem with ffmpeg which is actually driving me mad...
I try to use FFMPEG's filter_complex in order to extract certain short segments of a videofile (shot at 60fps). I know the exact frames from the original footage which i want to use for cutting. I use the [trim](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#trim) filter command together with [setpts](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts), if i want to change the speed of each snippet.
In the actual case i want to have the first snippet in original speed (1.0), and the resulting output video should be at 30fps instead of the original footages 60fps.
Here's the code i'm using:

```
ffmpeg -y -i footage60fps -filter_complex " 
[0:v]trim=start_frame=28:end_frame=82,setpts=PTS-
STARTPTS,setpts=1.0*PTS[v0]; 
[0:v]trim=start_frame=10:end_frame=20,setpts=PTS-
STARTPTS,setpts=2.0*PTS[v1]; [v0][v1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[out] " -map [out] -
preset ultrafast -r 30 output30fps.mp4
```

The result i'm expecting would be, that in the first snippet (frame 28 until last before 82) ffmpeg would drop every second frame ([x]) in order to have it converted from 60fps to 30fps at normal speed:
    [28][x][30][x][32][x]...[80]

However, the result i get is:
    [28][29][30][31][x][33][x][35][x]...[81]

Does anybody understand this behavior? How could i solve it? It seems like a minor issue, but it turns out to be so annoying when cutting sharp on music etc... Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -y -i footage60fps -filter_complex " 
[0:v]trim=start_frame=28:end_frame=82,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,framestep=2[v0]; 
[0:v]trim=start_frame=10:end_frame=20,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,setpts=2.0*PTS[v1];
[v0][v1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[out]" -map [out] -r 30 -preset ultrafast output30fps.mp4
```

I haven't looked into the reasons for the behaviour you see but when you mix differing rate streams like this with the concat filter, and apply a CFR rate conformance, the cadence of frame drops isn't always as expected.

Comment: This seems to work! Thank you so much @Mulvya